# Nginx Fuelphp VHost Config - File Not Found

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting, fuelphp

I am trying to setup my first fuelphp project in ubuntu12, php5 and nginx, Im following their tutorial in http://ucf.github.io/fuelphp-crash-course/#Every_Building_Needs_A_Scaffold

The problem Im having is when Im trying to access my app URL

```
http://localhost/public/messages
```

the error is "file not found"

The rewrite rule im using is

```
root /path/to/project;
index index.php index.htm index.html;

location / {
       try_files $uri $uri/ @handler;
       expires  30d;
}        

location @handler {
       rewrite ^ /index.php?/$request_uri;
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: $request_uri already has a leading slash in it. So you shouldn't add another one again.

Answer (score 0):

root /path/to/project;

I assume you are changing this to reflect the actual path to the public directory of your project?  If not, you need to

Comment: its not only root path to project, it should be root /path/to/project/public folder. Since fuelPHP has its routing via public folder all the requests are served via this folder, so, no need to expose other core app files or your controllers and models.

Answer (score 0):

After researching on this, I just found out that I did not even need to modify the .htaccess on my fuel/public/.htaccess

I fixed the problem by setting AllowOverride All in my Vhost config, enabled mod_rewrite and restarted my apache

Thanks

Comment: Your question talks about NginX. On this answer you are talking about Apache and .htaccess. Make up your mind!

Comment: Are you using just Nginx or Nginx in front of Apache ? Nginx doesn't really have anything to do with .htaccess. If you make your case clear here, I can help you with the config, As I am running Nginx successfully with FuelPHP.